# Reporting engine architecture

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema of events in mongo which is as follows,

```
{
timestamp:Time,
event:"Event1" or "Event2" or "Event3"
}
```

I need to sort all this data on perday basis, how many times each event occours in a calender day, and I should also follow local time settings.

```
{
day:9th April 2014,
events:{
    Event1: 5,
    Event2:10,
    Event3:5
    }
}
```

I also need to display a report, where you can see the total event counts by specifying a date range, which sums up all the numbers in events belonging to the date-range.

I am using Node.js, Express with mongo.

In which format should I store the date, so it is easier to store and retrieve or per day basis.

How to I find(all the events happening in a single day) from events schema.

I came up with something like this

```
function fetchRecordsOfDay(date, callback){
Record.find({timestamp:{"$gte": date, "$lt":date.setDate(date.getDate()+1)}}).exec(function(err, obj){
   if(err){
       console.error(err)
   }else {
       callback(obj)
   }
});
```

which gives me an empty result set because

> date.setDate(date.getDate()+1)

offsets the date by +1 as well

Comment: That certainly looks doable, although the timezone stuff might be tricky.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Right now I am stuck at how to find the calender date from the timestamp and aggregate them.

Comment: First, you don't describe your timestamp format, so it will be hard for anyone to offer suggestions.  Second, the aggregation should be pretty simple.  Third, I'm not sure what you mean about following local time settings, but if you're trying to use User's time from your server, it will definitely be tricky.  If you want to group them according to the same timezone as used by the server, that should be straightforward.

Comment: Timestamp format is standard javascript/mongo Time() datatype

Comment: ... which I don't happen to know, and don't feel like looking up just to answer your question.  :-)